# Onbeforeunload fires before onhashchange in IE10?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, internet-explorer-10, onbeforeunload

We use both onbeforeunload and onhashchange to do two separate things:

1) onhashchange displays a special tooltip asking the user to use application controls for navigation

2) onbeforeunload is used to warn the user that they will loose data if they close the app or try to navigate away to a different URL altogether

This implementation works perfectly on all browsers but IE10. For some reason in IE10, onbeforeunload fires before onhashchange and it causes the wrong thing to display.

Is this a known issue? Is there something special about IE10 I need to know?

Implementation is in Dojo, if that helps...

Comment: Um. I would really appreciate it if someone answered this already?

Comment: PLEASE ANSWER THIS QUESTION, PLEASE!!!